# Getting all items with another Eloquent query ID in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have something like this:

```
$items = Item::whereIn("name", $request["names"])->get();
```

Now I want to get a list of shops that have any of those items. Something like this:

```
$shops = Shop::whereIn("item_id", $items)->get();
```

This does not work, because items is an eloquent collection (obviously). I could do some loop and get all the ids like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    $itemIds[] = $item
}
```

And then use it, but I feel there must be a cleaner way.

Any help?

Comment: Also sidenote, if `$request['names']` is an array, you'd want to use `->whereIn('name', $request['names'])`, or rename the field to just `name`. The singular/pluralization of a word should match what it returns; `name` for a single name, `names` for multiple, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `->pluck('id')` and `whereIn()`:

```php
$items = Item::where('name', $request['names'])->get();

$shops = Shop::whereIn('item_id', $items->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Eloquent Collections have access to many of the same functions of Laravel's Collection Class:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods

`->pluck('id')` will return an array of all `items.id` records, which you can then use to query via `->whereIn('item_id', ...);`

Comment: that whereIn reminder saved me yet another headache. Thanks :)